# Stop ad from overlapping on last item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, admob

On my layout I'm showing an ad at the bottom. The layout as a `FrameLayout` where the content is loaded, the `AdView` and an `ListView`to show the navigation drawer.

The `FrameLayout` is loaded with an `ListView` and for the last row of the `ListView` not being overlapped with the ad, I've created this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightgrey">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentsboth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ads:adUnitId="111111111111111111111111"
                    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/orange"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/menulist_selector"
            android:background="@color/lblack"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is working as expected. The problem is that when I have the network disconnected, my `FrameLayout`, since theres no add to show, it's not taking the all height of the screen. The "space" for the add is shown. Basically it shows one empty rectangle.

**How can I change my layout so that when there is no network the `FrameLayout` takes all the height of the screen and when there is network, the ad can be shown but without overlapping the content of the `FrameLayout`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the `android:id="@+id/adContainer"` to the `LinearLayout` containing the ad and set it's visibility to `gone`and and on the code, did this:

```
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adContainer);
            adContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```